# Союзное слово в роли обобщающего при однородных членах предложения

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, спп

Могут ли союзные слова быть обобщающими при однородных членах?

Правильно ли писать так:

**Всё то, за что мы любим видеоигры: графика, сюжет, геймплей, — есть только на приставке Playstation 4.**

"Что" — это союзное слово; чтобы не спутать с союзом, его можно заменить на указательное слово. Заменим на слово "это".
Перефразируем придаточное, превратим его в самостоятельное предложение:

**Мы любим видеоигры за это: за графику, за сюжет, за геймплей.**

Значит, союзное слово "что" может быть обобщающим, а в придаточных предложениях, стало быть, могут быть однородные члены и обобщающие слова, чью роль способны выполнять, как в данном примере, слова союзные.

Правильна ли цепь моих рассуждений или неправильна?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше, по-моему, сделать так:

***Всё то, за что мы любим видеоигры,  — графика, сюжет, геймплей — есть только на приставке Playstation 4.***

Здесь запятая после слова "видеоигры" закрывает придаточное, двумя тире выделены однородные члены "графика, сюжет, геймплей".

Ср.:

***Всё, что могло приглушить звуки,  – ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома.***

См. *[Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. "Орфография и пунктуация", М., 2008]:*

> Однородные члены предложения могут отделяться от обобщающего слова
>   знаком тире…
>
> Если однородные члены находятся в середине предложения и возникает
>   необходимость представить их как выражение попутного, уточняющего
>   замечания, тире ставится с двух сторон:
>
> *Всё, что могло приглушить звуки,  – **ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель** – Григ давно убрал из дома* (Пауст.);
>
> *Для всего, что существует в природе,  –  **воды, воздуха, неба, облаков, солнца, дождей, лесов, болот, рек и озёр, лугов и полей,
>   цветов и трав**  –  в русском языке есть великое множество хороших
>   слов и названий* (Пауст.).
>
> (Однородные члены предложения выступают как вставка.)

**P.S.**

В разбираемом нами предложении *обобщающим словом* является **цельное словосочетание** "всё то" (являющееся в предложении подлежащим),  распространённое придаточным "за что мы любим видеоигры":

***Всё то, за что мы любим видеоигры,*** — графика, сюжет, геймплей — есть только на приставке Playstation 4.

Comment: Я всё-таки считаю, что слово "всё" является определением. Подлежащее "то", а слово "всё" это признак предмета, который можно спокойно изъять из предложения. Подлежащее "то" при этом никак не пострадает и не изменит своего смысла. Значит сочетание синтаксически разделить можно, и поэтому оно уже нецельное.

Comment: _Хай Дзяо: …слово "всё" можно спокойно изъять из предложения. Подлежащее "то" при этом никак не пострадает и не изменит своего смысла._ === Да, "всё" можно изъять. Но можно изъять и "то". См.: _Всё, за что мы любим видеоигры, — графика, сюжет, геймплей — есть только на приставке Playstation 4._  === И что теперь будет подлежащим?

Answer (score 0):

Всё то, за что мы любим видеоигры: графика, сюжет, геймплей" — есть только на приставке Playstation 4. (Запятая после однородного ряда не нужна).

Сравним: **Всё это: графика, сюжет, геймплей" — есть только на приставке Playstation 4.** Здесь обобщающим словом является местоимение "то" (с определением "всё"). В заданном варианте это обобщающее слово **распространено придаточным предложением.**

Примеры:

Всё, **что могло приглушить звуки:** ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель – Григ давно убрал из дома.

В памяти осталась лишь картина, **увиденная в окно вагона**:  багровая полоса заката и длинный силуэт города с башнями.

Comment: Запятая после однородного ряда нужна, потому что она закрывает придаточное предложение.

Comment: Двоеточие поглощает эту запятую.

Comment: В моём предложении слово "всё" — это определение, а подлежащее — это слово "то".  "Всё то есть на только на приставке Playtation 4". Вот главное предложение с подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: В моём предложении слово "всё" — это определение, а подлежащее — это слово "то". "Всё то есть на только на приставке Playtation 4". Вот главное предложение с подлежащим и сказуемым.

"За что мы любим видеоигры: графика, сюжет, геймплей". Вот придаточное предложение, где слово "что" — обобщающее для ряда дополнений.

Придаточное открывается и закрывается запятой, получаем:

"Всё то, **за что мы любим видеоигры: графика, сюжет, геймплей**, — есть только на приставке Playstation 4".  
Это тире ничего не поглощает, оно вообще больше интонационное.

Comment: Правило Розенталя: Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире: Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотоаппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об интересном госте? (Пришв.);  Тире здесь ставится по правилу, а запятой в конце ряда нет  У Лопатина (ПАС):  В этом рассказе вы найдете почти всё, о чем я упоминал выше: сухие дубовые листья, седого астронома... и многое другое (Пауст.).

Comment: Это образцы для  предложений с обобщ. словами, на них надо ориентироваться. Стандартная структура, где в роли обобщающих слов выступают местоимения  или сущ. с обобщенным значением, союзные слова там ни при чем. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113   и      http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php

Comment: Правило Розенталя: Постановка перед тире также запятой в качестве дополнительного пунктуационного знака связана с условиями контекста, т.е. обусловлена каким-либо другим правилом, например: С большой и сердечной любовью относились к Чехову и все люди попроще, с которыми он сталкивался: слуги, разносчики, носильщики, странники, почтальоны, – и не только с любовью, но и с тонкой чуткостью, с бережностью и пониманием (Куприн) (запятая закрывает придаточное предложение и открывает присоединительную конструкцию). Тире в моём предложении не обязательно, а вот запятая нужна. Она закрывает придаточное

Comment: Присоединительная конструкция не входит в состав простого предложения, это не ваш случай.  Присмотритесь ВНИМАТЕЛЬНЕЕ к структуре своего предложения:  это обобщающее слово с распространителем + однородный ряд + продолжение предложения.  А в примере у Розенталя однородный ряд стоит в КОНЦЕ основной части предложения, а далее следует присоединительная конструкция. И вот чтобы обозначить границу ряда, приходится ставить запятую,  а тире отделяет присоединительную часть. (Здесь можно считать тире и запятую единым знаком)..

Comment: Перед тем как работать с осложненными вариантами, очень желательно хорошо изучить три основные схемы  расположения  обобщающего слова и однородного ряда в простом предложении.

Comment: В примере у Розенталя запятая закрывает не границу ряда, а придаточное предложение. А далее может следовать или присоединительная конструкция, или, может, другое предложение — это уже неважно.Запятая нужна в любом случае.

Comment: Ведь чётко написано: «...запятая закрывает придаточное предложение». Так и в моём предложении.

Comment: Уважаемый Хай Дзяо, я с большим уважением отношусь к вашему убеждению в своей правоте, но , к сожалению, наши точки зрения не совпадают. Но может быть, другие участники форума Вас поймут и поддержат.