# Правильна ли пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильна ли пунктуация в следующем предложении:

*Где бы он ни был — в Баку, Тифлисе или Батуми, — всюду ему чудился Эдем, земной рай, жить в котором должны, однако, не праведники, а поэты.*

Нужно ли второе тире?

Comment: Наталья, не стоит объединять два разных вопроса в одном. Пожалуйста, оформите вторую часть как отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос непростой. См. обсуждение подобного вопроса здесь:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429652/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, пунктуация верна.

Похожие примеры с двумя тире из Нацкорпуса:

*Где бы он ни был ― на работе, на улице, дома, ― все ему казалось: кто-то неотрывно за ним наблюдает. [Владимир Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975)]*

Всюду, где бы он ни был ― в любом городе Европы, в балканских столицах, в Шанхае или в Америке, ― он видел все одно и то же, несмотря на разницу стран: ресторанные стены, оркестр, эстрада, те же слова тех же романсов, та же музыка, тот же шницель по-венски, та же водка; менялись только женские лица, да выражения глаз, да волосы, да голоса, да тела. [Гайто Газданов. Ночные дороги (1939)]

Артем, где бы он ни был, ― вез ли с гумна мякину, или чистил овцам ясли, ― завидев Дуняшу, втыкал вилы и шел к ней, вышагивая на длинных ногах, как верблюд. [А. Н. Толстой. Детство Никиты (1919-1922)]